# How do I define WebParameters in C# Web service so that my WSDL reflects the same?

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

I am trying to generate web parameters so that my WSDL has the property names
Currently this is how my web service result  looks:

```
<ArrayOfAnyType>
<anyType xsi:type="ArrayOfAnyType">
<anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">A123</anyType>
<anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">FYP</anyType>
<anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">1.347821</anyType>
<anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">103.682924</anyType>
<anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">Simtech</anyType>
<anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">Simtech</anyType>
<anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">30/4/2009 6:08:37 AM</anyType>
<anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">100843.00</anyType>
<anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">simtech_order1</anyType>
</anyType>
```

How do I define WebParameters in C# Web service so that my WSDL reflects the same?

Comment: HI John, Thanks for responding!
I think am probably not using the correct term. What I want to do is add a "name" element to the xml along with the type. Since right now it says anytype - and since there is no name either - I am having difficulty in reading this data when sent to my android project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here! 
They aren't called web parameters or anything like that. 
Its an element name.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1638752.aspx/1